# example where business logic is mixed with UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC pattern using .NET. I am very new to this pattern. This question has been asked many times - "Why MVC?". When I google it, every article highlights the idea of separating business logic from UI, such that change in either of these can be done without affecting another. They also had examples of how this was achieved. But none of them showed an example where change in business logic/UI affected the other
But I was looking for an example where change in either of one affects other. This would help me increase my understanding over MVC.
Thanks in advance....

Comment: not able to understand ur question sir..

Comment: I was looking for an example that doesnt follow MVC pattern - an example where change in UI affected business logic or vice versa.

Comment: Think about showing records for a user based on their department. This should never be controlled in the ui layer.

Answer (score 0):

When we think of business logic in mvc, we are looking at the model part of mvc - which is based on the business domain objects. Therefore, if there is a change to the business domain - e.g. If we have an "asset" domain and add an asset number to the asset domain object and start recording details based on this, we would update our model with a new asset number property containing various attributes. Then our view would display the asset number based on those attributes e.g visible to asset administrators only - done by decorating the model attributes. In this way, changes in the business domain objects get reflected in the model part of mvc.

Answer (score 0):

An example would be most Excel applications

For example some key piece of data is saved to cell C1

A macro is hard coded to pick up the data in cell C1 and perform operations on it

Then someone thinks it would look better if the sheet had a title so that information is moved to C3 fit the title in and all of the excel code stops working.

The logic in the code is tightly bound to the user interface and a change in the user interface requires a change to the business logic (the code or calculation).